# How to conditionally write code that's dependent on lambda's return type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, std

I have function that invokes callback for every element it iterates:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void iterate( const auto & on_element ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i ) {
        //here I want to stop iteration if function returns bool true:
        if constexpr ( is_same< result_of( on_element )::type, bool >::value )
            if ( ! on_element( i ) )
                return;
        //but when callback doesn't return bool - simply iterate the whole range:
        else
            on_element( i );
    }
}

int main() {
    const auto & stop = [&]( const int & element ) {
        cout << "stop" << endl;
        return false;
    };
    iterate( stop );

    const auto & whole = [&]( const int & element ) {
        cout << "    " << element << endl;
    };
    cout << "Whole:" << endl;
    iterate( whole );
}
```

I compile it with `g++-10 -std=gnu++2a -fconcepts main.cpp -o main` and get these errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void iterate(const auto:1&)’:
main.cpp:7:69: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
    7 |         if constexpr ( is_same< result_of( on_element )::type, bool >::value )
      |                                                                     ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/type_traits:582:12: note: provided for ‘template<class, class> struct std::is_same’
  582 |     struct is_same;
      |            ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:7:78: error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘)’ token
    7 |         if constexpr ( is_same< result_of( on_element )::type, bool >::value )
      |                                                                              ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void iterate(const auto:1&) [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(const int&)>]’:
main.cpp:21:20:   required from here
main.cpp:8:30: error: could not convert ‘(& on_element)->main()::<lambda(const int&)>(i)’ from ‘void’ to ‘bool’
    8 |             if ( ! on_element( i ) )
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              void
main.cpp:8:30: error: in argument to unary !
```

Before I managed to reason about function return values, but somehow can't achieve it in this case. Is it because of callable being lambda or due to usage of `auto` qualifiers?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us, and then please also show us the exact errors you get.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing that out! Managed to get simplest example and resulting error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`on_node` is not a name in your example, and `std::result_of` doesn't have that syntax (and is deprecated in favor of `std::invoke_result`).

I think you mean

```
std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(on_element), int>, bool>
```